# Jboss eap 6.4 to Wildfly 14/18 Migration

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jboss, wildfly

I need to migrate a webservices application from Jboss to Wildfly and i'm not sure what code changes i will require.

I already modified the Standalone file according to my project.
What changes i need to do in my pom.xml file for wildfly?

Comment: We'd have to see your code and/or `pom.xml` file. Much depends on how you've written it.  A standard JAX-RS application shouldn't be too difficult but if you've pulled in other libraries there may or may not be an issue.  Can you post a portion of an existing service?

Comment: I'd also recommend having a look at the JBoss/Wildfly quickstarts.  You should be able to get a good idea of the current dependency versions.

Comment: hi @stdunbar i cant post any code here coz its against the policy of my organization